# DataGrid Width has no affect in Windows Mobile Psion Omnii Xt15

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

this is the code I am using to set up the column styles...  but it only works on windows CE5  but when i use it on the latest Mobile Psion Omnii Xt15 then the widths are ignored, and only display with about 20pixels per column, all squashed up.

This is the DataTable I am using to bind the grid..

```
    /// <summary>
    ///Represents the strongly named DataTable class.
    ///</summary>
    [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("GetTypedTableSchema")]
    public partial class ContainersDataTable : global::System.Data.DataTable, global::System.Collections.IEnumerable {

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnContainer_ID;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnScanValue;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnLkContainerType_ID;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnParentContainer_ID;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnQuantity;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnContainerType_Text;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnScanValueDisplay;

        private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnGenComment;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public ContainersDataTable() {
            this.TableName = "Containers";
            this.BeginInit();
            this.InitClass();
            this.EndInit();
        }
```

this is the code I am using to set up the column styles...

```
 private void InitializeContainerGrid()
    {
        DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle {MappingName = "Containers"};

        // container type 
        DataGridColumnStyle unitCol = new DataGridTextBoxColumn
                                          {
                                              MappingName = ContainerType_Text,
                                              HeaderText = "Unit",
                                              Width = 50
                                          };
        ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(unitCol);

        // scan value
        DataGridColumnStyle scanValueCol = new DataGridTextBoxColumn
                                               {
                                                   MappingName = "ScanValueDisplay",
                                                   HeaderText = "Scan Value",
                                                   Width = 110
                                               };
        ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(scanValueCol);

        // number of fruit
        DataGridColumnStyle fruitNoCol = new DataGridTextBoxColumn
                                             {
                                                 MappingName = Quantity,
                                                 HeaderText = "Fruit",
                                                 Width = 50
                                             };
        ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(fruitNoCol);

        containerGrid.TableStyles.Add(ts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the resolution on the Psion is double that of other devices.. so whilst it looked like it wasn't setting the width, it actually was... just HALF what I was expecting due to double the resolution.